# Managing multiple releases on Pip?

Tags: python, pip, package

I am maintaining a Python package on PyPI that uses Python 3.7+, which uses type-hints and f-strings. However, I also want to have separate releases of my code that work for Python 3.4+ and above. I don't want to remove all of my type-hints, so what is the easiest way to maintain and develop these two separate versions?

The only way I can currently think of is to tag my releases separately, such as `v1.0-3.4` or `v1.0-3.7`. But won't this mean that whenever I make a new release to v1.0-3.4, everyone who downloads the latest release will get the 3.4, rather than the 3.7 version?

What I basically want to have happen is:

- Person using Python 3.4 to 3.6 -> `pip install <my-package>` gives them the 3.4 version of my code.
- Person using Python 3.7+ -> `pip install <my-package>` gives them the 3.7+ version of my code.

Currently, I am achieving this via automated tooling. I have a `src/` directory with all of my files. Outside of `src/` I have a setup.py that takes a single package and wraps it for distribution.

To obtain the 3.4 code, I run an automated script that automatically removes all type-hints and converts my f-strings to format strings, as well as removing/changing a few specific lines I have specified. My project is only a few files, so I am not concerned about maintaining both versions in the future. It then produces a `src_build/` folder that matches `src/` file for file.

As a result, the packages are exactly identical, except one works for 3.4+ and one works for 3.7+. The reason I want to keep both is because the 3.7 one allows users to type-check their code, and supports a few extra features (generalized tuple unpacking, f-strings, etc), while the 3.4 one caters to previous versions of Python.

I am very new to publishing packages on Pip, so any clarification would be very useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Set the right [classifiers](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#classifiers) in `setup.py`.

Comment: You **really don't want to do this**. There are no classifiers that'll help with this (@KlausD's suggestion **won't work**).

Comment: Instead, produce one release that can work on all supported versions. Even if you have to bundle two directories and have `setup.py` pick one when installing.

Comment: @KlausD. classifiers are only useful to help search on PyPI, install tools do **not** use those to select what distribution to install. It even says so right there in the documentation you link to: *this information is only used for searching & browsing projects on PyPI, not for installing projects*

Comment: You could experiment with the [`python_requires` field](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires), but I'm not sure that even with recent tooling a Python 3.4 user will be given the 3.4 version and the 3.7 user the 3.7 version. `python_requires='>=3.4, <3.5.*'` for the 3.4 variant and `python_requires='~=3.7'` for 3.7, 3.8, etc. (but not 4) *may* be sufficient, but do you really want to track multiple packagings?

Comment: By bundling two directories, do you mean something like `if sys.version_info < (3, 7): setuptools.setup(...version=3.4) else: setuptools.setup(...version=3.7)` ?

Comment: Before thinking about how to package this project, would you mind showing how you organized your code? For example, do you have two source code repositories, or just one? Do the two versions live in separate directories next to each other or are both versions of a module (<3.7 and >=3.7) in the same directory? Are you going to maintain 2 versions of the same code? Can you guarantee the behavior of both versions is going to be similar enough to declare it as 1 single _MyThing_ project? What about publishing under 2 project names _MyThingAlpha_ and _MyThingBravo_ instead?

Comment: I updated the question with this information! ^
Both versions essentially accomplish the same thing, but 3.7 introduces a couple additional features that are only possible with the newer version. As a result, they should keep the same project name, but be downloadable under different versions.

Comment: @zephyrnx: why not just *put those in the same codebase*? Type hints go into a `.pyi` file, and *just not use f-strings and tuple unpacking*.

Comment: @zephyrnx Your goal is a bit unusual. And seems somewhat not worth the trouble. **1.** Python 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 are old versions that have reached their end of life or are about to, maybe you'd consider not supporting them at all. **2.** As far as I know type hinting is optional, you can add type hints and the same code would still work with older Python versions. **3.** Features such as tuple unpacking and f-strings are just alike to syntactic sugar, in that they don't bring anything new, just another way of writing the same thing, so really you could decide to just not use them at all.

Comment: Seems like this is not a supported use case on PyPI, so it looks like I will just have to remove some of the newer features. Thank you for all of your help!